# Using Wordpress on 000webhost.com

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp

hello and I am a new web developer and I have been trying to get wordpress to work on the following site

https://000webhost.com/

I have followed all the steps, altering the wp-config.php file properly and uploaded it using a FTP to the database as is given to me when I downloaded all the files onto my tablet, I do not know if I missed a step I do not know or if I messed something up accidentally. If anyone can tell this poor newbie of Wordpress what he is doing wrong I will greatly appreciate it.

Thank you for taking the time to read and respond to this

Comment: 1. We don't know what your problem is. 2. 000webhost is going to have restrictions as it's a free host, if you're serious about the site, spend a few dollars.

Comment: There is no info here to help us diagnose. You need a lot more information

Comment: Have you run https://000webhost.com/wp-admin/install.php  which should complete the installation and activate it if you have completed the wp-config.php file correctly. You may have seen this but it usually works well if followed closely The famous "Five Minute Install"  https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress#Famous_5-Minute_Install

Comment: Try without the https and use http only - I could not even get onto their main site using https but it redirects from http.  
Ahhh no add the www - it goes nowhere without it! https://www.000webhost.com/wp-admin/install.php  should take you to your start page if you are running WordPress on you webroot.

Comment: Further ahhh...Perhaps you have just set up your domain name and its DNS has not propagated yet - some server providers give you a temporary IP address to get access but I would advise waiting until your site index page shows up with your own domain name as putting the IP address into WordPress and then trying to change it in WordPress later can be just as hard sometimes! Propagation can take a couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, 000webhost doesn't support php. Once I tried to run a .php file and when I went to it, it displayed the actual code, not what I told it to write. So my suggestion, use a paid web host or a blog service.